# How to replace repeating alphabets into one

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have a vector with repeating letters like this:

```
x <- c("b b b b", "a a ")
```

I would like to remove repeated characters so that each vector contains only its one unique character. The output looks something like this:

```
"b", "a"
```

I've found other solutions to remove repeated items, but they all involved a vector of characters, rather than a string with spaces in between. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 5):

Here is one regex based approach using `sub`.  First, I remove all spaces in the strings.  Then, I do a replacement on the following pattern:

```
(.)\\1{1,}
```

and I replace with `\\1`.  The logic here is to match and capture a single letter, then replace it, along with any of the *same* letter which follows, by just that single letter.  This effectively does what you want here.

```
x <- c("b b b b","a a ")
x <- gsub("\\s+", "", x)

result <- gsub("(.)\\1{1,}", "\\1", x)
result
[1] "b" "a"
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following. R has the built-in constant `letters`. Separate `x` into single characters, and subset `letters` based on that.

```
letters[letters %in% unlist(strsplit(x, ' '))]

[1] "a" "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another beautiful package to work with strings in R is `stringr` from the `tidyverse`;

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("b b b b","a a ")
x <- str_replace_all(x, "\\s+", "")
unique(unlist(str_split(x, boundary("character"))))
#> [1] "b" "a"
```

First remove all the extra spaces and then split the strings into characters.

This solution is a bit more verbose but in essence same as [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52056024/4524755)'s answer. Although I would argue it's easier to understand for a `regex` novice such as myself.